# Splat Route Not Found (DurandalJS)

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I have `settings` splat route configured in shell.js:

```
router.map([
   { route: 'settings*child', moduleId: 'views/settings/main', nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

And inside the `views/settings/main.js` file i've created child router:

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({
    moduleId: 'views/settings',
    fromParent: true
}).map([
   { route: 'users',     moduleId: 'child/users/list', nav: true },
   { route: 'users/:id', moduleId: 'child/users/view', nav: false },
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

the folder structure is look like this:

```
/views  
-/settings  
--settings.js      
--settings.html  
--/child  
---/users  
----list.js  
----list.html  
----view.js  
----view.html
```

**The problem** i am faced is:

When i try to navigating to the settings (#settings) page from another parent route page it will show me an error message in console:

`Route Not Found settings undefined`

But the settings page is still showed up with all list of child router i've created.

Next, I try to navigate to the `#settings/users` and `#settings/users/{id}` and it work with no problem or error eventhough try it from another parent page.

I think the problem is splat route is always expected something would be in front of the hash by something like `#settings/users` and it **WILL NOT** accept `#settings` without the child ?

Or i've missed something on my implementation ?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciate!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a very similar setup, I create a route on the child router to represent the blank route like this:

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({
moduleId: 'views/settings',
fromParent: true
}).map([
   { route: '', moduleId: 'main', nav: true },
   { route: 'users',     moduleId: 'child/users/list', nav: true },
   { route: 'users/:id', moduleId: 'child/users/view', nav: false },
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

Comment: Hi @patel, Unfortunately i don't have a chance to test your suggestions yet now. But I believe this is the answer. I missed to create blank route { route: '', moduleId: 'main', nav: true }, Thanks!